# How render specific fields from Layout cshtml in C#

Tags: c#

I have pages like Home.cshtml and layout.cshtml. Header, Menu bar and Footer In layout.cshtml.
 I want only Header and Footer in my Home.cshtml, How to get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
@Html.Partial("PartialViewName")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways yo can do so

1) Static way : have one more layout which contains only Header and Footer , then use this layout to create current layout and menu . Now for rest of the page use the second layout and for home use the first layout

2) Dynamic : In you layout have the condition to check the current page or action if it is Home hide the menu

Comment: 3) Make the Menubar-Section optional with default Content in the layout.cshtml using "IsSectionDefined" and override that section in Home.cshtml with empty content